# AVI file not playing in windows media player?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-media-player

I am creating AVI file using **gwavi** library.
can check the  [gwaviLib link](http://doc.gw-computing.net/libgwavi/gwavi_8c.html) . We are using Win32 API to create the AVI file.

I am the AVI file by capturing the images. The images is saved in a output stream in PNG format. So when the library creates the AVI successfully , I am not able to open the AVI in Windows media player. It opens up properly in VLC media player.

So, I thought that there is some issue with the Windows media player.

But then I saved the captured images in the output stream in JPEG format. This time the AVI created opened in the Windows media player as well.

So, I am not able to decipher that why the AVI created with PNG images have the issue playing in Windows media player and not the JPEG images created AVI.

But with JPEG images the quality of the AVI decreases as it is compressed images so I need to use PNG images to create the AVI file but in this case it is not opening in the Windows media player but playing properly in the VLC media player.

So  what is the actual problem in playing the AVI created using PNG images ?
Is it the Windows media player problem or the issue is with the [gwaviLib](http://doc.gw-computing.net/libgwavi/gwavi_8c.html) ?

Need help !

Comment: You could use something like GSpot to look at both files and see if there is a difference in headers/codec.etc,

Comment: I don't think there is a stock decoder for PNG video in Windows. If you install a third party VCM/ICM codec to handle that, Media Player would start playing the files back. It is a good chance that ffdshow can do the job (either default configuration, or with PNG explicitly enabled).

Comment: so this is the limitation of the media player and to overcome it I will have to download the codec ? @RomanR.

Comment: It is not the limitation exactly. Windows Media Player, like any other player, does not support every video/audio format available around. It leverages APIs to read and decode files, and there is no standard codec available for video backed by PNG frames. VLC is built to have it out of the box, Windows APIs on the opposite don't have it. So if you need WMP to play that out, you need to extend the APIs by installing third party extension.

Comment: i used the GSpot tool and it says the MPNG codec is missing i.e., PNG images decoder. I installed the missing MPNG codec and now the AVI opens but is blank and in the GSpot tool it still shows the same message that MPNG codec is missing. @RetiredNinja

Comment: Thanks..GSpot was helpful. :) @RetiredNinja

Comment: i installed ffdshow(default configuration)..the avi is working perfectly fine now :) @RomanR.